# How to persist entities using collection in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, collections, entity, persistence

I'm trying to persist entities in OneToMany relationship using JPA. I have two entities, Proyecto (Project) and Participacion (Participation). Proyecto can have multiple Participacion. The problem is when i try to persist a Participacion to an existing Proyecto.

```
//First, I get the selected project by the user from the database.
Proyecto proyecto = proyectoManager.getProyecto(Integer.parseInt((String) session.getAttribute("idProyecto"))); 

//Second, I create and set the Participacion parameters, including the project.
Participacion participacion = new Participacion();
participacion.setIdProyecto(proyecto);
participacion.setLogin(usuario);
participacion.setPorcParti(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("porc")));

//Finally I persist participacion with his respective project
proyectoManager.addParticipacion(participacion);

//Here, I'm trying to get the project to check if his Participacion collection contains the new participation.
proyecto = proyectoManager.getProyecto(Integer.parseInt((String) session.getAttribute("idProyecto")));
```

The problem is in the second time I recover the project from database, because his participation collection doesn't contain the new participation. I've tried using edit() method and even flush after persist() method but it doesn't work.

The next time I deploy the Enterprise Application, the project contains his respective participations, including the new one, but I need it after persist the first time, without deploying again.

Can any one help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How do you tell JPA that you want to cascade persist the collection?

I mainly use annotations on my domain objects, and usually just add something like:

```
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```

This (or similar) question has been answered many times on this site.

**Edit**

Also, from the code sample above, it seems as you are not adding the Participation instance to the Project. I would think that you need something like:

```
    proyecto.addParticipation(participation);
    proyectoManager.saveProyecto(proyecto);
```

to complete the association.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I have in my Project entity: `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idProyecto",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`

Comment: Ok, from the code sample above, it is not obvious to me that you are adding the Participation to the Project. Rather you seem to be adding the participation to the Project manager (which I guess is NOT a domain object?)

Comment: Project Manager is a stateless java bean that calls to em.persist(entity). I thought that persisting the participation with his respective project, is also added to the project implicitly.

Comment: No, that is not enough... It seems as if you are setting up a connection between `Proyecto` and `Participation` that's intendet for two-way navigation. This would also require an annotation in the Participation object. I can't remember the correct Annotation right now, but you'll easily find it elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you but i don't understand if it is not enough why the second time i deploy and recover the project from DB contains all of his participations into the collection. It seems as the persistence was correctly made.

Comment: Hm, Have you looked into the differences between `em.persist(entity)` and `em.merge(entity)`? It would be useful to have a look at the internals of your `ProyectoManager` for further ideas..

Comment: JPA does not manage bidirectional relationships for you.  If you are only setting one side, hopefully the owning side, the change will not be reflected in the 'other' side until the object model is reloaded from the cache.  This is why you see it after a restart, or if you were to call em.refresh, but it is much better just to set both sides of your bidirectional relationships, and be sure that both entities are merged for changes to be reflected in the cache.